# Are there any official rules regarding studying books?

Tags: dnd-5e, downtime

I have one simple question: Are there any official rules regarding studying books? Any kind of books really. For example, if I spend 10 days downtime studying books does my Intelligence or Wisdom increase, or do I learn anything if I study books regarding a subject?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know of Manual of Quickness of Action. I found some very nice Homebrew content on dmguild that I will be using. I will attach the link later.